# initrd.img doesn't point to the newly (and newer) installed kernel

Tags: kernel, initrd

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

I was on `5.8.16-050816-generic`, this kernel version was installed by downloading from Ubuntu's mainline.

Just recently, I manually build kernel `5.14.0-next-20210913+` grabbed from upstream linux-next tree. I did update initrd, and grub. But one thing I notice and curious. Why `initrd.img` still points to the old kernel version, but `vmlinuz` points to the newest one. See below.

```bsh
$ ls -lah /boot
total 396M
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep 14 22:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4.0K Dec 18  2020 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 253K Sep 14 21:18 config-5.14.0-next-20210913+
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 243K Apr 12 20:47 config-5.8.0-50-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 242K Oct 17  2020 config-5.8.16-050816-generic
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Sep 14 21:43 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   32 Jun  6 19:41 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.8.16-050816-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  71M Sep 14 22:05 initrd.img-5.14.0-next-20210913+
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  75M Jul 27 06:48 initrd.img-5.8.0-50-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  51M Jun  6 17:26 initrd.img-5.8.0-50-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  74M Sep  4 10:00 initrd.img-5.8.16-050816-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  74M Jul 27 06:48 initrd.img-5.8.16-050816-generic.old-dkms
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 Jun  6 19:16 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.8.0-50-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 179K Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Aug 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 5.6M Sep 14 21:18 System.map-5.14.0-next-20210913+
-rw-------  1 root root 5.3M Apr 12 20:47 System.map-5.8.0-50-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 5.4M Oct 17  2020 System.map-5.8.16-050816-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   29 Sep 14 21:18 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.14.0-next-20210913+
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M Sep 14 21:18 vmlinuz-5.14.0-next-20210913+
-rw-------  1 root root 9.4M Apr 12 22:17 vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  14M Oct 17  2020 vmlinuz-5.8.16-050816-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   29 Jun  6 19:41 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.8.16-050816-generic
```

What might be the issue?
Is it safe for me to manually re-link symlink of `initrd.img` myself to point to the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

Even rEFInd runs an old version of the kernel, in the latest Ubuntu build, although rEFInd used to track files in ascending order and run Ubuntu from the current version of the xx-generic file.

Idlers broke Ubuntu.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd3UX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LSmu.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean whatever file `initrd.img` points to would not be any of concern? I didn't use rEFInd. But would you mind telling me which file your `initrd.img`, and `vmlinuz` points to in your image?